# Why does pyautogui.click() return a Type Error?

Tags: python, typeerror, pyautogui

I am trying to make a script that can detect if an eye is open or close. I am doing this by using the code below.

https://github.com/balajisrinivas/Color-Detection-OpenCV

Thank you to balajisrinivas for providing the code!

Using this code I can add live video capture and create a single image that is refreshed every 2 seconds in a while loop instead of a single image(colorpic.jpg being used as an example). Also, I made it so that if the colour is brown or has an RGB near brown the computer beeps but if the colour is white, black, or the colour of your iris then it knows your eyes aren’t closed. There is one problem. The problem is that I have to click on the image to get the results but I want it to happen automatically. So, I used if `pyautogui.locateOnScreen(‘needle.jpg’, confidence=0.8)` instead of `if clicked` in the `while True:` loop. The picture ‘needle..jpg’ is a picture of my eye. After that I added `pyautogui.click(‘needle.jpg’)` which would click the center of the picture and give me the result of an open or closed eye without a manual click.

Where I am getting stuck:

```
while True:

    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('needle.jpg', confidence=0.8):
        pyautogui.click('needle.jpg')

        # cv2.rectangle(image, start point, endpoint, color, thickness)-1 fills entire rectangle
        cv2.rectangle(img, (20, 20), (750, 60), (b, g, r), -1)

        # Creating text string to display( Color name and RGB values )
        text = get_color_name(r, g, b) + ' R=' + str(r) + \
            ' G=' + str(g) + ' B=' + str(b)
```

Before the code was:

```
while True:

    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    if clicked:

        # cv2.rectangle(image, start point, endpoint, color, thickness)-1 fills entire rectangle
        cv2.rectangle(img, (20, 20), (750, 60), (b, g, r), -1)

        # Creating text string to display( Color name and RGB values )
        text = get_color_name(r, g, b) + ' R=' + str(r) + \
            ' G=' + str(g) + ' B=' + str(b)
```

The only problem is that I am getting a Type Error.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Color-Detection-OpenCV\hello.py", line 89, in <module>
    pyautogui.click('needle.jpg')
 line 598, in wrapper
    returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 980, in click
    x, y = _normalizeXYArgs(x, y)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Just to let you know I am a newbie in python and I am a school student. If you know the answer to why I am getting this error please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the relevant part of your own code?  I can tell you're using `locateOnScreen` and `click` incorrectly, but it's hard to explain what you should be doing instead if the code isn't available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's just intended oversight from pyautogui. Because we already know where image is on your `locateOnScreen` call, so why we search again when clicking.

From their source code:

```py
def _normalizeXYArgs(firstArg, secondArg):
    # skip
    
    elif isinstance(firstArg, str):
        # If x is a string, we assume it's an image filename to locate on the screen:
        try:
            location = locateOnScreen(firstArg)
            # The following code only runs if pyscreeze.USE_IMAGE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION is not set to True, meaning that
            # locateOnScreen() returns None if the image can't be found.
            if location is not None:
                return center(location)
            else:
                return None
# skipping lines past this
```

At last we see comment saying that `locateOnScreen` return None if image is not found.

For your call on `locateOnScreen`, you passed `confidence=0.8` but *default confidence is 0.999*.

So with confidence 0.8 image is found, but not with 0.999. Therefore it returned `None` to `location` and then it lead if block to return `None` - which is not unpackable.

Since I am currently on mobile I can't test myself, but I bet `locateOnScreen` returns x, y coord when matched.

so try change if block into something like this.

```py
try:
    x, y = pyautogui.locateOnScreen( ~~~ )
except TypeError:
    # value unpack failed, so we got None. Therefore no image matched.
    # therefore no x exist.
    # Put things you want to do when there's NO image matched.
    pass
else:
    # Put things you want to do when image matched.
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

I strongly suggest reading official document of [Error handling part](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried what you mentioned above but I am still getting the error.                                           `                                                                                                    C:\Users\nahal\Desktop\Color-Detection-OpenCV>python test#2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nahal\Desktop\Color-Detection-OpenCV\test#2.py", line 70, in <module>
    x, y = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('needle.jpg')
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object                                                         '

Comment: Oh right, change `except ValueError` to `except TypeError`

Comment: This is my code.                                                                                                            while True:
    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    try:
        x, y = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('face_image_eyes.jpg')
    except TypeError:
        # value unpack failed, so we got None. Therefore no image matched.
        print('no image')
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
 # do other things
I still am getting a different error.
no image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\hello.py", line 78, in <module>
pyautogui.click(x, y)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: Are you 100% sure you followed the code? If there's typeerror then it SHOULD return and break out, not continuing excution. That try-except is basically replacing `if` block, or program will try to use undefined value which is `x`. I updated code again for more clarity.

Comment: I made it work after using the else statement and using pass. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Don't forget to check Stackoverflow tour [Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to better learn how to use the site!